# Runtime error in CodeForces but not on VisualStudio

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find my runtime error here. I compiled my code on visual studio and it seems fine, but when I run it in CodeForces, it gets runtime error. Here's the link to the codeforce problem https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1478/B
Here's my code:

```
def func():
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    for i in range(a):
        u = int(input())
        if u >= b*10:
            print("YES")
        elif u%b==0:
            print("YES")
        else:
            while u > 0:
                u=u-10
                if(u<=0):
                    print("NO")
                    break
                elif(u%b==0):
                    print("YES")
                    break


cases = int(input())
for i in range(cases):
    func()
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: @ForceBru None. It only says RUNTIME_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

function input() means get one line from input buffer stream, I hold the view that you chould correct your code in corresponding position.